# Visual Studio Magic Keywords in Comments

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I know visual studio has some magic keywords you can use in comments, which will make them marked in the Task List:

- TODO
- HACK
- UNDONE

Do you know of any other built-in keywords, that may mark the code as a task?

Or any other special keywords that will mark the code as bug-fix, warning, error, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Visual Studio 2005 lets you modify the list of these.

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Task List`

Answer (score 3):

Mine has `UnresolvedMergeConflict` as part of the list.

Just in case you didn't know (hard to tell from your question), you can edit the list via `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Task List`.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to dredge this old (but very useful) question up.

I would like to add that if you also use ReSharper it highlights them in a bold and different colour. The ReSharper list is more powerful (regex) and can be found under `ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> To-do Items`.

Strangely by default it doesn't match the Visual Studio list so it might be a good idea to standardise them. I have just added the missing ones from each to the other one and then added my own new ones to both.

> **Note:** To simplify adding new ones you can copy (duplicate) the `Todo` one and then just change the word `TODO` in the regex: `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>`***TODO***`)(\W|$)(.*)` with your new word. Then a simply give it a new Title, and make any changes to the colour/icon and save.

Comment: CRUD items: `Extensions -> ReSharper -> Options... -> Tools -> To-do Explorer`

See the items in solution/project/file: `Extensions -> ReSharper -> Tools -> To-do Explorer`